# Identify r output

Tags: r, package

i'm working on a project and I've forgot which code and package I used to get the following output;

[image]

I need these value labels from SPSS to combine with some other output. But the code has just left my script and my brain.

Do you recognize the output? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you describe your problem (what the output should summarize) and provide some example data we can help you much better.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your output.

Comment: The output should show the valuelabels, and the count of each to the right. And print each label down. [link](https://imgur.com/a/LCKQD)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code, the community can help if you post your `df` and your desired output.

Package wise, we can also just guess it looks like a `knitr::kable` output or when you mention `SPSS` maybe you used `gmodels::CrossTable` [Example](http://intersci.ss.uci.edu/wiki/index.php/R_CrossTab%2C_gmodels_package)

Hope that gives you a hint.

Comment: The df is huge and consists of 338 variables. Each of them coded with value labels from SPSS. I have used sjt.frq(TNL_HO[1:338]) to  get nice HTML prints to use for some documentation I was asked for. But sjt.frq could not handle value.labels. So i want to print the value labels for each variable is a quick manner. Sorry, I'm new to this community, although, I've read it for years.